# Having problem in delete query with laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, sql-delete, delete-row, destroy

Hey i am facing a problem in delete query .
my Controller code is

```
 public function destroy($id)


 { 


   $employee= Employee::findorfail($id);

   $employee->delete();

    return redirect('/employee');
 
 }
```

and view code is

```
<form action="/employees/{{$employee->id}}">
  <input type="hidden" value="DELETE" name="_method">
  <input type="submit" value="DELETE">

</form>
```

but still it is not deleting the record

Answer (score 0):

1. Can u check if you are getting value in $id
2. You can use find() instead of findOrfail()
3. If delete() method is still not working, you can use Employee::destroy($id) instead.

Refer: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#deleting-an-existing-model-by-its-primary-key